# gcc precompiler directive __attribute__ ((__cleanup__)) vs ((cleanup)) (with vs without underscores?)

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm learning about gcc's [cleanup attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes), and learning how it calls a function to be run when a variable goes out of scope, and I don't understand why you can use the word "cleanup" with or without underscores. Where is the documentation for, or documentation of, the version *with* underscores?

The gcc documentation above shows it like this:

```
__attribute__ ((cleanup(cleanup_function)))
```

However, most code samples I read, show it like this:

```
__attribute__ ((__cleanup__(cleanup_function)))
```

Ex:

- http://echorand.me/site/notes/articles/c_cleanup/cleanup_attribute_c.html
- http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/atomic_8h_source.html

Note that the first example link states they are identical, and of course coding it proves this, but how did he know this originally? Where did this come from?

Why the difference? Where is `__cleanup__` defined or documented, as opposed to `cleanup`?

My fundamental problem lies in the fact that *I don't know what I don't know,* therefore I am trying to expose some of my unknown unknowns so they become known unknowns, until I can study them and make them known knowns.

My thinking is that perhaps there is some globally-applied principle to gcc preprocessor directives, where you can arbitrarily add underscores before or after any of them? -- Or perhaps only some of them? -- Or perhaps it modifies the preprocessor directive or attribute somehow and there are cases where one method, with or without the extra underscores, is preferred over the other?

Comment: The first link you presented hints at (if not outright states) that `cleanup` and `__cleanup__` are identical. Further, given that you've tagged this as C++, I'll also mention that it appears that its best purpose is using RAII semantics in C style code. In general in C++ you should wrap things that need to be cleaned up into a class which has a destructor (and implies -- through the rule of three or rule of five for c++11 or newer -- that you also need constructors and/or movement operators).

Comment: Thanks. I expounded upon my question a bit more. The first link does state they are identical, but I'm wondering what this implies for other attributes I use....are there always multiple options of the same thing? How did this guy know they were identical? Certainly some reason for the difference must exist. See my updated answer for a few of my wonderments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax explains:

> You may optionally specify attribute names with `__` preceding and following the name. This allows you to use them in header files without being concerned about a possible macro of the same name. For example, you may use the attribute name `__noreturn__` instead of `noreturn`.

(But note that attributes are not preprocessor directives.)

Comment: Thanks. What are attributes then, if not preprocessor directives? How are preprocessor directives defined? Also, is there a term "compiler directive"? How does that differ?

Comment: Preprocessor directives are things like `#include`, `#define`, `#ifdef`, etc.

Comment: What do you call `__attribute__` then? If not a "directive," what's a good word for this type of thing?

Comment: It's a (nonstandard extension) *keyword*.

Answer (score 7):

You are allowed to define a macro `cleanup`, as it is not a name that is reserved to the compiler. You are not allowed to define one named `__cleanup__`. This guarantees that your code using `__cleanup__` is unaffected by other code (provided that other code behaves, of course).